# why are my media queries not working when i change the numbers around?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass, media-queries

Hello people of stackoverflow,

I was wondering if any of you could please help me with finding out why when I change the @media widths that have values of 1109px to 609px why cant I see the green background anymore.

```
    /* pink */
@media (min-width:1410px) {
    .mmQ2{
        display: none;
    }.pop:hover{
        opacity:1;
    }*{
        background: hotpink;
    }
}

/* blue */
@media (min-width:1109px) and (max-width:1410px) {
    *{
        background: lightskyblue;
    }
    .header{
        width:90vw;
    }.nav__links li{
        display: none;
    }.blue--link li a:hover{
        display: none;
    } a{
        display: none;
        
    }.mmQ_nav__right{
        float: right; 
        margin-left: 10px;
    }.cards > ul {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(46%, 45%));
    }.savemoney--swingtag{
        display: none;
    }.savemoney--mobile{
        padding:10rem 8.0rem;
        position: relative;
        left: 2%;
    }.savemoney--swingtag{
        padding: 0rem;
        margin-right: 0%;
    }.savemoney--text{
        width: 80%;
    }.savemoney--parent__calendar{
        width: 100%;
    }.savemoney--parent__purple{
        width: 80%;
        left:5%;
        margin-left: 10%;
    }.savemoney--save{
        margin-left: 10%;
    }.airports{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        
    }.airports--parent h2{
        font-size: 25px;
    }.main--container__airports{
        padding:5%;
    }main{
        grid-template-columns: 100%;
    }.bucketlist--main__containeer{
        height:200vh;
    }.childofbox1{
        margin:7% 3.75%;
    }.box1{
        margin: 2% 0%;
    }main{
        height:50%;
    }.bucketlist--main__containeer{
        height:5%;
}
}

/* green */
@media  (min-width:1px) and (max-width:1109px){
    *{
        background: green;
    }

}
```

When the values are 1109px I am able to see a pink background on large screens, blue on medium sized screens and green on the smaller screens.

When the values are 609px it skips the green stage and goes straight to blue.

why is this please?

thank you for all your help in advance :)

Comment: AFAIK its working as expected, from 1-609 green, then blue then pink.. ?

Comment: @johnSmith sorry i sent in 1109px already change to 609.

Comment: It's working just like expected for me, both ways...Firefox

Comment: @ajarrow when its 609px do you see green blue and pink?

Comment: I see green when I'm at 609px, 610px gives me blue, 1410px: blue, 1411px: pink

Comment: mine doesnt show green it just shows blue and pink

Comment: Is the actual website the full width of the screen or is there an editor or something on the side?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221967/discussion-between-ajarrow-and-maya-wright).

Comment: ive made the website 100vw. im not sure what you mean by editor or something on the side. ive checked through my code and there arent any other media queries on any other pages